# How to programmatically check/set access permissions to a network drive?

Tags: c#, permissions, network-drive

How do you check to see if you have access (yet - because it will work fine after you have navigated there at least once before in this windows session and entered name/pass) to a network drive without waiting for the IOException when trying to access it?

And on that note, suppose that I can get my users name/pass via dialog, how do I set their access permissions to that network folder?

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think it is better to just handle the exception instead. You can't be 100% positive that you have access between checking and trying to access a drive. Not to mention all the other errors that could happen.